# Is there a way to make a window "ghost"?

Tags: xfce, xfwm4

In many window manager (I'm using XFCE4's xfwm) there is an "Always On Top" option which I use very often. However, when some controls left behind that window, it becomes a time consuming task to make that window minimized and then maximized.

Is there a way to turn the "Always On Top" window into a "ghost" window which woudn't block my interactions with the background application and will become way transparent while the mouse pointer is hovered on it?